# Java UnitTest multiple command Line input from System.in

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to test a function that loops forever until `QUIT` is entered but I can't figure out how to simulate multiple lines of user input from system.

This is what I currently have

```
String validStartFlow = "START-FLOW\r\nQUIT\r\n";
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(validStartFlow.getBytes());
System.setIn(in);
CommandLineListener cmdLineListener = new CommandLineListener(eventBus,logger);
cmdLineListener.startCommandLineListener(in);
```

The method that loops forever is

```
while (!userCmd.equals("QUIT")) {
    userCmd = "";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
    // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);

    while (userCmd == null || userCmd.equals("")) {
        userCmd = scanner.nextLine();
    }

    ...
}
```

The `START-FLOW` is read in perfectly but then after that when it reaches `scanner.nextLine()` it crashes with the following error

> No line found java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

How can I get it to read in `QUIT` from the `validStartFlow` string?

Comment: Did you try `scanner.useDelimiter("\r\n")`?

Comment: Just tried that and it's still failing for the same reason. Thanks for the input though I didn't think of that EDIT: Wait during debugging I noticed that it's actually skipping START-FLOW and going straight to quit when I call nextLine?

Comment: EDIT EDIT: It was because I was checking scanner.nextLine() in my debug console so in the code it was going straight to quit because start-flow was already read in. @DelfikPro you were totally right and my problem is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new `Scanner` on every iteration and access `nextLine()` only once each.

Try extracting it from the loop:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
scanner.useDelimiter("\r\n");
String userCmd = "";

while (!userCmd.equals("QUIT")) {
        userCmd = scanner.nextLine();
...
```

Comment: Good catch! I didn't notice that. But your previous comment of setting the delimiter solved it so ima do both. Thanks again my guy. If you edit this comment to have the set delimiter all set your question as solved